# email via server

Tags: php, ios, xcode, email

I have an app where people can fill in some data and send it to my email. The mail is sent and working fine except that the body of the mail is empty.

My method for the connection:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if( !(buttonIndex == [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) ) {

        NSString *post  = nil;
        post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Naam spel = %@ Uitleg= %@", spelnaam.text ,Uitleg.text];
        NSLog(@"dit wordt verstuurd %@", post); //works fine!

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.nl/theemailfile.php"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        [ NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self ];

        [post release]; 
        [self displayAlert];
    }
}
```

My php file:

```
<?php
 $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
 mail( "emailadres@gmail.com", "Test Message", $message );
?>
```

Comment: You need to isolate whether this is your client app or whether this is your server. You have control over both, yes? First off, make certain "`postData`" is not null right before you do your `NSURLConnection` (e.g. set a breakpoint in Xcode).

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in mail API to send the email?

Comment: With the built in mail Api the user must have an email account enabled

Comment: The nslog shows that the postdate is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTTP request, you're saying that the information you are sending in the body of the request is of the type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, however that isn't the case.  It appears to just be free-form text.  You should conform to [the format described in the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).  You are sending a message that looks like this:

```
Naam spel = test Uitleg= test
```

You need to send something like this:

```
message=This+is+a+test&other=test
```

Comment: Well the message is the string 'post' wich contains naam and uitleg.